# Is it possible to block requests for my MAC address?

Tags: mac-address

If a java application makes a request for my MAC address can I block it in any way? Are there any security programs which can do this?

--
What I am asking is if there is anyway I can prevent Java applications from knowing my MAC address.

Comment: A Java application runs with full privileges, so you can't restrict that. But if you run the code as an applet, then it is sandboxed, and I don't think it can get your MAC address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you do not want network connectivity, then it's not possible. Furthermore blocking for a specific application is not possible.

A MAC address is requested using ARP. ARP is a layer 2 protocol (arguably layer 2.5). ARP is used to allow connectivity between you and a router (which is a layer 3  device).  An application is located at layer 7, which is the top of the OSI model.

ARP is nescesary to allow local layer 3 connectivity. It's used to know which devices are on the LAN network.

If you are concerned about people knowing your MAC address, then this means you are allowing some malicious entity onto your network. To prevent this you can use 802.1x, which is the Port-based Network Access Control. This works both for physical as wireless networks.

If you are not in control of the network, then there is little you can do.